# Android Gradle with Extra Unused Dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

There are four libraries in my app as follow:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
```

with extra dependencies [see image]:

[image]

### Now States of Every Dependency:

**appcompat-v7:**

```
Library stats - click for more information
    com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0 [5705]
Dependencies (some might be shared with other libraries): [13458] 
    com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0 [183]
    com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 [32]
    com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 [6564]
    com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 [1992]
    com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 [929]
    com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0 [1377]
    com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 [1983]
    com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 [2]
    com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0 [396]
```

**Design support library:**

```
Library stats - click for more information
    com.android.support:design:25.2.0 [2749]
Dependencies (some might be shared with other libraries): [22434] 
    com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0 [183]
    com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0 [5705]
    com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0 [2405]
    com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0 [32]
    com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 [6564]
    com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 [1992]
    com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 [929]
    com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0 [1377]
    com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 [1983]
    com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 [2]
    com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0 [396]
    com.android.support:transition:25.2.0 [866]
```

Questions:

- As we think about size of apk, Is it required to exclude dependencies which is common in that?
- If **design-support** library has **appcompat-v7** then is it required to add **appcompat-v7?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> As we think about size of apk, Is it required to exclude dependencies which is common in that?

Gradle does it for you. It doesn't add the same dependency twice.

> If design-support library has appcompat-v7 then is it required to add appcompat-v7?

No, it is enough to add the design library.
Gradle will download for you all the nested dependencies, then also the appcompat-v7 library.